# Ciclo hamiltoniano demorando demais

Tags: c, grafo, ciência-da-computação

Tenho que descobrir se há ciclo hamiltoniano em um grafo gigante (1000 vértices na menor instância e 5000 vértices na maior).

Minha ideia inicial foi fazer backtracking, e em instâncias pequenas, funcionou direitinho. Mas para instância de 1000 vértices, deixei 6 horas e nada de resposta.

Minha ideia foi pegar um código do caixeiro viajante pronto (só achei usando matriz) e coloquei as arestas que existem com peso 1, e as que não existem com peso 9.

Caso o resultado da execução da função dê o número de vértices, existe um ciclo hamiltoniano.

Caso não dê, então não existe um ciclo hamiltoniano (pois teve que usar alguma aresta de peso 9 para encontrar o caminho).

Para instâncias pequenas, continuou dando certo, porém com a instância de 1000 vértices, travou também.

Ninguém da turma tem conhecimento para fazer algo que fuja muito do backtracking, logo, supõe-se que encontremos algum código já implementado na internet. No máximo, deveremos fazer algumas alterações pequenas.

Alguém tem algum caixeiro viajante ou um código que detectaria um ciclo hamiltoniano com lista de adjacência? Ou instâncias até 5000 em menos de 3 horas?

Teria como alguém tentar me ajudar dando pelo menos uma dica?

**Links com os códigos e entradas que usei:**

- Segue o link do código que usei (em C): http://ideone.com/qyEipK
- Instâncias que necessito passar: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/50ij1m5w5b1mfca/AADzt3XsE9cVg6OlW6SDTygQa?dl=0
- Segue o link de uma lista de adjacência: http://ideone.com/Ib9i0P
- Segue o link de um código que fiz para transformar a lista de adjacência em um arquivo de matriz: http://ideone.com/7stdkJ
- Segue o link de uma matriz pequena N=18 que contém um ciclo hamiltoniano: http://ideone.com/M8PfTu
- Segue o link de uma matriz pequena N=18 que não contém um ciclo hamiltoniano: http://ideone.com/GBlyZ5

Comment: Se o código não for muito extenso, edite a pergunta e adicione ele. Título da pergunta deve dar uma ideia sobre o problema, da forma que está parece meio estranho.

Comment: Considerando que você está tentando obter um algoritmo que resolva um problema NP-completo, isso significa que provavelmente não existe algoritmo que te dê a resposta em tempo razoável em todos os casos. Entretanto, o caso típico é bem diferente do pior caso, então vou pensar em alguma abordagem que consiga dar uma resposta em tempo razoável em "quase todos" os casos. Para ajudar, você poderia descrever mais sobre esses grafos, eles são grafos aleatórios, têm alguma estrutura peculiar ou são grafos particularmente criados com o propósito de serem difíceis neste problema?

Comment: Editei o título da pergunta, pois (1) não está dando crash nenhum e (2) o seu "Porque?" você já sabe - é porque o grafo é muito grande.

Comment: Victor Stafusa, quando coloquei para executar o código em uma maquina da Universidade, ubuntu, i7 5a geração, 8gb de ram, em 4 minutos apareceuca mensagem "Morreu". Editarei o topico com as instâncias que devem ser lidas.

Answer (score 2):

Determinar se um grafo possui um **ciclo hamiltoniano** é um problema NP-Completo (Fonte: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem)).

Problema **NP-Completo** significa que não há algoritmo polinomial conhecido para encontrar uma solução (apenas para checar se uma solução é válida).

Os algoritmos como força-bruta (backtracking, complexidade n!), programação dinâmica (n²2^n) ou outros mais sofisticados são todos exponenciais.

O que sugiro é pesquisar **meta-heurísticas** para resolver este problema de maneira sub-ótima (Ant Colony, Hill Climbing, Algoritmos Genéticos) - vai acertar muitas vezes, mas pode falhar para algumas instâncias de grafos. Pelo menos você terá mais controle sobre o tempo de execução e a qualidade das soluções.